# How can I define mutations or queries without any parameters in graphql?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql, nestjs

I have a problem with graphql:

```
type Mutation {
    clearEsLog(): string
    clearRabbit(): string
}
```

I use Nestjs and when I run the app the error is:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you don't have arguments in your queries or mutations, you must leave out the brackets `()`:

```
type Mutation {
    clearEsLog: string
    clearRabbit: string
}
```